# Updating data realtime in Node.js express website

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, pug

I'm trying to achieve something what I think should be very simple to do, but all the tutorials and examples I find seem to be an overkill.

What I am doing:
I'm fetching weather info periodically, and I want to update the text on the website everytime its fetched without user having to refresh the browser.

Almost every tutorial on realtime data updating recommends using socket.io and I have given it a try, but I can't get it to do what I want and I'm starting to think that there should be an easier way and that socket.io might not be the best way to go about this. Any suggestions? How do I get simple line of text update on website without user having to refresh the page?

My weather script:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


function refreshWeather() {
    var temperature = getTemperature();
    io.sockets.emit('broadcast', {
        temperature : temperature
    });
}
```

My jade script:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/index.css')
    title Dashboard
  body
    script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
    script.
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('broadcast', function (data) {
      // UPDATE WEATHER HERE
      });

    .main-content
      h1 Weather is: // I WANT THIS TO BE UPDATED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

- Get rid of socket.io.
- Make an end point for retrieving the temperature.
- Do some polling on the frontend.

Backend would look something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/weather', function (req, res) { 
    res.send(getTemperature()) 
});
```

Frontend would look something like this:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/index.css')
    title Dashboard
  body
    .main-content
      h1(id='weather') Weather is: // I WANT THIS TO BE UPDATED
    script.
      setInterval(function () {
        fetch('/some/url', {
          method: 'get'
        }).then(function(response) {
          // UPDATE WEATHER HERE
          document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML = response
        }).catch(function(err) {
          // Error :(
        });
      }, 1000) // milliseconds
```

Code is totally untested, so please try not to copy and paste — adapt it instead. Also, if you're going to use the [fetch API](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch), you might want to use a [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch), otherwise, just use plain [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

Comment: In this case does the /some/url have to be /temperature? Also my main issue here is that I don't know how to update frontend once I get the data. Could you kindly elaborate on the frontend code? For example showing how to show response as a text in website.

Comment: @Shard no problem, I just edited the answer to include the frontend update. Basically, you have to interact with the [D.O.M.]. I assigned an id of "weather" to the h1 element. Used "document.getElementById('weather')" to get a reference to the element and updated its "innerHTML" property with the text from the server. Since your question is more about an alternative to socket.io, please consider opening another question for your (D.O.M.) related questions and also consider marking this question as correct (click the check mark on the top-left side of the question). I hope that helps.

Comment: In node or the browser? The "document" global variable should be available in the browser (frontend), you must be doing something odd.

Comment: Sorry I had old piece of code around. Your answer did it, thanks! :)