# Real-time update data in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I need some help.
I've been thinking about doing a `real-time update` using expressjs.
But I don't know how to do it. So I just wanted your help.

---

I wanted these options to update every second. And I'm using `discord.js` and `express.js`

---

## Screenshots

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Tga.jpg)

---

## Codes

`routes/api.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const api = express.Router();

api.post("/dashboard/guild/:id/prefix", function(req,res) {
  req.db.set(`prefix_${req.params.id}`, req.body.prefix)
  // console.log(req.body)
  res.json({prefix: req.body.prefix});
})
api.get("/dashboard/guild/:id/channels", function(req,res) {
    var data = req.client.guilds.cache.get(req.params.id);
    res.json(data)
})
function isAuth(req,res,next) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
  req.session.backURL = req.url;
  res.redirect("/auth/login")
}

module.exports = api;
```

`views/tab/home.ejs`

```
<p class="m-3 text-2xl">Editing <span id="server">{server_name}</span>:</p>
<div id="toast-default" class="fixed flex bottom-1 opacity-0 items-center w-full max-w-xs p-4 text-gray-400 bg-gray-800 rounded-lg m-3 shadow transition-all duration-300" role="alert">
      <div class="inline-flex items-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 w-8 h-8 text-green-200 bg-green-800 rounded-lg ">
        <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414l-8 8a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 011.414-1.414L8 12.586l7.293-7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-3 text-sm font-normal">Success! All changes are saved.</div>
</div>
<form id="form" method="post" action="/api/dashboard/<%=g.id%>/prefix" class="m-4">
<center>
<label for="prefix">Prefix:</label>
<br>
 <input type="text" name="prefix" id="prefix" class="rounded-2xl text-white bg-slate-700" value="<%=db.fetch("prefix_${g.id}")?db.fetch("prefix_${g.id}"):req.client.config.botPrefix%>" required/>
 </center>
 <br>
 <br>
    <br>
<br>
<center>
  <label for="logs">Mod Logs:</label>
     <br></br>
  <select id="logs" name="logs" class="bg-slate-900 border border-slate-900 rounded w-64 text-center">
        <option value="false">Off</option>
        <%req.client.guilds.cache.get(g.id).channels.cache.filter(e => e.type==="GUILD_TEXT").forEach(c => {%><option value="<%=c.id%>"><%=c.name%></option><%})%>
    </select>
    <p id="log"></p>
    <div class="m-4">
 <button class="float-right bg-[#5271FF] p-2.5 md:p-2 hover:bg-[#3d5aff] rounded-[15px]  transition-all duration-200" type="submit" id="submit" onclick=''>Save Changes</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

### Thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602748/updating-data-realtime-in-node-js-express-website
Maybe this will help you? :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.